# The keyboard shortcuts are completely different from that of Windows

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, word-in-context

I came across this sentence in an "actual speaking", and had seen similar examples in English context too many times. Nevertheless, my question is about whether the author had to use **"those"** instead of **"that"** since **"keyboard shortcuts"** is plural and **"that"** is referring to it.

> Excited as I was to possess such an item, I found myself experiencing
> certain discomfort to familiarize myself with the Mac system.**The
> keyboard shortcuts** are completely different from **that** of
> Windows.

Comment: You are correct; because the subject is plural ("keyboard shortcut**s**"), the speaker should have said **those**.  But people often make mistakes like that when they're speaking or writing informally.

Comment: ***shortcuts*** is plural, so they should be contrasted with ***those** ["other shortcuts", of Windows]*.

Comment: Although this is not directly relevant, I’d like to point out that all of the “major” shortcuts (cmd/ctrl A, Z, X, C, V, and P) are exactly the same on Mac and Windows (and iOS).